# How Many levels are in Super Mario World?

Tags: wii-u, virtual-console, super-mario-world

I was playing Super Mario World on the Wii U the other day and my dad said that in order to "beat the game legitimately" you have to beat every level. How many levels are there?

Comment: To be clear - are you talking about playing Super Mario World (SNES) on the Wii U Virtual Console? Or are you talking about playing one of the New Super Mario Bros games?

Comment: I'm going to assume Super Mario World SNES version and his dad is talking about the Star World and Super World levels that he might not know about.

Comment: virtual console wasn't an option for a tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, you're dad was probably referring to finding all the exits from all the levels in the game

In the Super Nintendo version of the game, there are 96 exits total.  These are tracked on the load game screen immediately after the title screen.

Finding all of them will put a star next to the exit count.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this includes secret exits, so levels with a red dot on the overworld have to be finished twice.

Comment: Also, a few Ghost Houses have secret exits.  Those also count toward the total.

Comment: Every Ghost House except Vanilla Dome and Choco Island, from memory.